# React Router usage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm testing React Router in a project (It's one of my first times using it), and, for some reason the routes aren't working when i click the 'Links', but when I type the route directly in the url, and then refresh the page, it works, can someone help me with that?

Here's the code:

App Component

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import ProductList from "./components/ProductList";
import Home from "./components/Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/products" component={ProductList} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
```

NavBar Component (For now, I haven't included the 'My Cart' in the Links)

```
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-dark p-3">
      <Router>
        <Link to="/">
          <i className="fas fa-gifts fa-2x text-light ml-2" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/products" className="btn text-light bg-dark mr-2 ml-auto">
          Products
        </Link>
      </Router>
      <button className="btn text-light bg-dark">
        <i className="fas fa-shopping-cart" />
        My Cart
      </button>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: are your component export names Home and ProductList? in same casing

Answer (score 1):

This setup would work -

for App.js

```
import React from "react";


import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import ProductList from "./components/ProductList";
import Home from "./components/Home";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div >
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={NavBar} />
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/products" exact component={ProductList} />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

for NavBar.js

```
import React from "react";

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-dark p-3">

        <Link to="/">
          <i className="fas fa-gifts fa-2x text-light ml-2" />
          Home
        </Link>
        <Link to="/products" className="btn text-light bg-dark mr-2 ml-auto">
          Products
        </Link>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Did you change the navbar code as well? the changes are removing switch, place navbar inside the router, and remove router in navbar file.